# How to Send Email from Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am taking a tutorial for Django, but stuck at sending email from Django.
I am working on Django's built in django.contrib.auth  password reset views, it works fine, but doesn;t actually sends any email.
For Testing purpose, I am using below code example to send email, but it gives error which I don't know where to resolve.

```
(env1) C:\Users\crm>python manage.py shell
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail(
...     'Subject here',
...     'Here is the message.',
...     'email1@gmail.com',
...     ['email2@gmail.com'],
...     fail_silently=False,
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 51, in send_mail
    connection = connection or get_connection(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 34, in get_connection
    klass = import_string(backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djago'
>>>
>>>
```

My Settings.py configuration

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'djago.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USER_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email1@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your email configuration.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Thanks @Arjun, for pointing my silly typo mistake,I corrected it, but now getting diff error
`File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 69, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 700, in login
    raise SMTPNotSupportedError(
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
>>>`

Comment: @Aashutosh you have another typo also in your setting. check my answer